# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 after (dual boot) Windows start and updates

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have an old Asus laptop which worked nicely with dual booting OS. Ubuntu installed is the desktop version 18.04.

Once, when I tried to start Windows, it got caught up in a boot loop for some time. When I later stopped Windows and again started Ubuntu Linux, Ubuntu's sound is broken. I only can hear a click noise when I start a Youtube video or directly use aplay to play a wav file. Whether I use headphones or speakers makes no difference.

Now that Windows is working again, I checked and the sound works OK there.

I tried around with some tips from the Internet, which did not change anything.

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

> Wiedergabe: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16
>   bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono

$ `cat /proc/asound/cards`

> 0 [PCH ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf600000 irq 31

So it still does recognize the card.

The kernel is: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I booted with selection of the some weeks' older kernel, but it did not change.

I also tried this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio  
sudo alsa force-reload
```

but it changed nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment. Thank you very much for the troubleshooting you did before posting.

Answer (score 0):

After all this fuddeling around I found a **simple solution: put the laptop to sleep and wakeup again**.

Aaaah, sometimes simple things make you happy!